# Error when starting VirtualBox on Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu, and I am trying to install virtualbox. But I get this error. If anyone knows how to solve this, please, tell me.

```
Error:
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
available for the current kernel (2.6.32-042stab092.2) or it failed to
load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

   sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

*Edit: After ThomasW's answer this showed up:

```
ERROR ON LOG: Error log file:
Uninstalling modules from DKMS
Attempting to install using DKMS
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
Makefile:183: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel.
Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again. Stop
```

Comment: Open a terminal and do as the error message says. Call `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`

Comment: Also he needs to install some needed packages like make gcc kernel-headers and such. There's already a few answers here with that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the command that is being provided in the error, as well as recompile it.

First, start by installing `build-essential` to get the essential libraries for building things:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Next, run the command that error is specifying:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Comment: I get this error: Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)

Comment: @Joserex65 attach the content of that log file into your question as an edit, we need to see the exact error

Comment: Added! Error log file: Uninstalling modules from DKMS
Attempting to install using DKMS
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
Makefile:183: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.

Comment: Added! Check my last comment.

Comment: @Joserex65 I can't read that on my phone, can you add that to your original question as an edit instead of as a comment to my answer?

Comment: Added! Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

First, start off by following Thomas W.'s answer:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

followed by

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

To fix your error, run:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-headers-generic
```

Comment: I've already tried this, and it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

What did work for me :

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-amd64
```

replace amd64 by your architecture.